# unable to run kibana and logstash with elasticsearch

Tags: docker, logstash, elasticsearch-5, kibana-5

Elastic serach is running fine on 9201 port. But unable to run kibana and logstash with docker-compose.

For `logstash` it throws the error:

> Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an
>   error.

For `kibana` it throw warnings:

> "warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living
>   connections"

Below is the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  # Service 1 : elasticsearch
  elasticsearch-5-6:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.3
    container_name: elasticsearch-5-6
    ports:
      - "9201:9200"
    volumes:
      - /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-5-6.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
      - /var/elasticsearch/data/immunedata-5-6/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/
      #- /etc/elasticsearch/logging.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/logging.yml
      #- /var/log/elasticsearch/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs/
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster-elasticsearch-5-6
      #- bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xmx2048m -Xms2048m"
      # Disabling the xpack security as it costs after one month of free trail.
      - xpack.security.enabled=false

  # Service 2 : logstash
  logstash-5-6:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:5.6.3
    container_name: logstash-5-6
    ports:
      #- "5044:5044"
      - "5001:5001"
    volumes:
      - /etc/logstash/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
      - /etc/logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline
      #- /etc/logstash/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
      #- /var/logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xmx2048m -Xms2048m"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch-5-6

  # Service 3 : kibana
  kibana-5-6:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:5.6.3
    container_name: kibana-5-6
 ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    volumes:
      - /etc/kibana/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
      #- /var/kibana/immunedata-5-6/:/usr/share/kibana/data/
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - xpack.graph.enabled = false
      - xpack.ml.enabled = false
      - xpack.monitoring.enabled = false
      - xpack.watcher.enabled = false
      - xpack.reporting.enabled = false

    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch-5-6

  # Service 4 : elasticseach-head
  elasticsearch-head:
    image: mobz/elasticsearch-head:5
    container_name: elasticsearch-head
    # will not wait for elasticsearch to be ready.
    ports:
      - "9100:9100"
```

elasticserach.yml

```
cluster.name: immunedata-cluster-5.6
node.name: "immunedata-cluster-5-6.node-1"

# Elasticsearch in docker access different data directory, defined mapping directory in docker-compose.yml
#path.data: /var/elasticsearch/data/immunedata-5-6/
path.data: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/
#path.data: /var/elasticsearch/data

# NOTE : Since elasticsearch 5.x index level settings can NOT be set on the nodes configuration like the elasticsearch.yaml
#index.number_of_shards: 1
#index.number_of_replicas: 0

# Allow all host access
network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200

# To enable cross-origin resource sharing (Accessing on browser)
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin : "*"
```

logstash.yml file

```
http.host: "0.0.0.0"
path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
#xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.url: http://localhost:9201
##xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.url: http://elasticsearch:9201
#xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: logstash_system
#xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: changeme

xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
```

kibana.yml file

```
server.name: kibana
server.host: "0"
elasticsearch.url: http://192.168.56.10:9201
xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled: false
#elasticsearch.url: http://elasticsearch:9201
xpack.security.enabled: false
## Above I tired this - not working
#elasticsearch.username: elastic
#elasticsearch.password: changeme
#xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled: false
#xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled: true
# Extra:
ssl.verificationMode: false
```

Logs:

```
[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
elasticsearch-5-6     |     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_141]
elasticsearch-5-6     |     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_141]
elasticsearch-5-6     |     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_141]
elasticsearch-5-6     | [2017-11-26T06:07:57,084][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [immunedata-cluster-5-6.node-1] [gc][young][14][6] duration [18.2s], collections [1]/[18.5s], total [18.2s]/[23.5s], memory [178.2mb]->[79.5mb]/[1.9gb], all_pools {[young] [132.1mb]->[964kb]/[133.1mb]}{[survivor] [16.6mb]->[12.5mb]/[16.6mb]}{[old] [29.4mb]->[66.5mb]/[1.8gb]}
elasticsearch-5-6     | [2017-11-26T06:07:57,085][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [immunedata-cluster-5-6.node-1] [gc][14] overhead, spent [18.2s] collecting in the last [18.5s]
elasticsearch-5-6     | [2017-11-26T06:07:57,298][ERROR][o.e.x.m.c.i.IndexRecoveryCollector] [immunedata-cluster-5-6.node-1] collector [index-recovery] failed to collect data
elasticsearch-5-6     | org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlockException: blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];
elasticsearch-5-6     |     at org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlocks.globalBlockedException(ClusterBlocks.java:165) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
elasticsearch-5-6     |     at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.recovery.TransportRecoveryAction.checkGlobalBlock(TransportRecoveryAction.java:114) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
elasticsearch-5-6     |     at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.recovery.TransportRecoveryAction.checkGlobalBlock(TransportRecoveryAction.java:52) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
elasticsearch-5-6     |     at org.elasticsearch.action.support.broadcast.node.TransportBroadcastByNodeAction$AsyncAction.<init>(TransportBroadcastByNodeAction.java:256) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
elasticsearch-5-6     |     at org.elasticsearch.action.support.broadcast.node.TransportBroadcastByNodeAction.doExecute(TransportBroadcastByNodeAction.java:234) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
elasticsearch-5-6     |     at org.elasticsearch.action.support.broadcast.node.TransportBroadcastByNodeAction.doExecute(TransportBroadcastByNodeAction.java:79) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
elasticsearch-5-6     |     at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
elasticsearch-5-6     |     at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:142) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
elasticsearch-5-6     |     at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:84) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
elasticsearch-5-6     |     at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.executeLocally(NodeClient.java:83) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
elasticsearch-5-6     |     at 
elasticsearch-5-6     | [2017-11-26T06:08:45,238][WARN ][o.e.x.w.e.ExecutionService] [immunedata-cluster-5-6.node-1] Failed to execute watch [XYNCje-TQzKm9OLdiH60gQ_elasticsearch_cluster_status_60e3c208-acca-4462-ba47-0711279d8f5e-2017-11-26T06:08:35.573Z]
elasticsearch-5-6     | [2017-11-26T06:08:54,886][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [immunedata-cluster-5-6.node-1] [gc][young][63][9] duration [3.6s], collections [1]/[4.6s], total [3.6s]/[30.2s], memory [226.9mb]->[103.5mb]/[1.9gb], all_pools {[young] [127.5mb]->[1mb]/[133.1mb]}{[survivor] [16.6mb]->[11.3mb]/[16.6mb]}{[old] [82.7mb]->[91.2mb]/[1.8gb]}
elasticsearch-5-6     | [2017-11-26T06:08:54,886][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [immunedata-cluster-5-6.node-1] [gc][63] overhead, spent [3.6s] collecting in the last [4.6s]
logstash-5-6          | Sending Logstash's logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
elasticsearch-5-6     | [2017-11-26T06:08:55,988][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [immunedata-cluster-5-6.node-1] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[.watcher-history-6-2017.11.20][0], [.monitoring-es-6-2017.11.20][0]] ...]).
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:08:56,786][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"fb_apache", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/fb_apache/configuration"}
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:08:56,891][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"netflow", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/netflow/configuration"}
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:08:57,558][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"arcsight", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/x-pack-5.6.3-java/modules/arcsight/configuration"}
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:09:04,121][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch-5-6:9201/]}}
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:09:04,123][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch-5-6:9201/, :path=>"/"}
elasticsearch-5-6     | [2017-11-26T06:09:04,687][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [immunedata-cluster-5-6.node-1] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [eAlcHBJ2QVG58e0HJsgrdQ][immunedata-cluster-5-6.node-1][/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0] free: 1.9gb[7.4%], shards will be relocated away from this node
elasticsearch-5-6     | [2017-11-26T06:09:04,687][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [immunedata-cluster-5-6.node-1] rerouting shards: [high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes]
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:09:06,450][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch-5-6:9201/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch-5-6:9201/][Manticore::SocketException] Connection refused (Connection refused)"}
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:09:06,452][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:09:06,455][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Failed to install template. {:message=>"Template file '' could not be found!", :class=>"ArgumentError", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.4.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/template_manager.rb:37:in `read_template_file'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.4.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/template_manager.rb:23:in `get_template'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.4.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/template_manager.rb:7:in `install_template'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.4.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:58:in `install_template'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.4.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:25:in `register'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator_strategies/shared.rb:9:in `register'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:43:in `register'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:290:in `register_plugin'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:301:in `register_plugins'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:301:in `register_plugins'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:310:in `start_workers'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:235:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:398:in `start_pipeline'"]}
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:09:06,455][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//elasticsearch-5-6:9201"]}
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:09:06,462][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>2, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>250}
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:09:09,818][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline main started
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:09:10,341][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:09:11,460][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch-5-6:9201/, :path=>"/"}
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:09:11,484][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch-5-6:9201/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch-5-6:9201/][Manticore::SocketException] Connection refused (Connection refused)"}
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:09:16,491][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch-5-6:9201/, :path=>"/"}
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:09:16,500][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch-5-6:9201/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch-5-6:9201/][Manticore::SocketException] Connection refused (Connection refused)"}
kibana-5-6            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-11-26T06:09:21Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","config","deprecation"],"pid":1,"message":"Config key \"ssl.verify\" is deprecated. It has been replaced with \"ssl.verificationMode\""}
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:09:21,513][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch-5-6:9201/, :path=>"/"}
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:09:21,523][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch-5-6:9201/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch-5-6:9201/][Manticore::SocketException] Connection refused (Connection refused)"}
kibana-5-6            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-11-26T06:09:26Z","tags":["status","plugin:kibana@5.6.3","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:09:26,536][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch-5-6:9201/, :path=>"/"}
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:09:26,570][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch-5-6:9201/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch-5-6:9201/][Manticore::SocketException] Connection refused (Connection refused)"}
kibana-5-6            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-11-26T06:09:26Z","tags":["status","plugin:elasticsearch@5.6.3","info"],"pid":1,"state":"yellow","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
kibana-5-6            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-11-26T06:09:26Z","tags":["status","plugin:xpack_main@5.6.3","info"],"pid":1,"state":"yellow","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
kibana-5-6            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-11-26T06:09:29Z","tags":["status","plugin:graph@5.6.3","info"],"pid":1,"state":"yellow","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
kibana-5-6            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-11-26T06:09:29Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Request error, retrying\nHEAD http://elasticsearch-5-6:9201/ => connect ECONNREFUSED 172.21.0.2:9201"}
kibana-5-6            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-11-26T06:09:29Z","tags":["status","plugin:monitoring@5.6.3","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
kibana-5-6            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-11-26T06:09:29Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch-5-6:9201/"}
kibana-5-6            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-11-26T06:09:29Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:09:31,585][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch-5-6:9201/, :path=>"/"}
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:09:31,603][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch-5-6:9201/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch-5-6:9201/][Manticore::SocketException] Connection refused (Connection refused)"}
kibana-5-6            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-11-26T06:09:33Z","tags":["reporting","warning"],"pid":1,"message":"Generating a random key for xpack.reporting.encryptionKey. To prevent pending reports from failing on restart, please set xpack.reporting.encryptionKey in kibana.yml"}
kibana-5-6            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-11-26T06:09:33Z","tags":["status","plugin:reporting@5.6.3","info"],"pid":1,"state":"yellow","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
kibana-5-6            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-11-26T06:09:33Z","tags":["status","plugin:xpack_main@5.6.3","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from yellow to red - Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch-5-6:9201.","prevState":"yellow","prevMsg":"Waiting for Elasticsearch"}
kibana-5-6            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-11-26T06:09:33Z","tags":["status","plugin:graph@5.6.3","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from yellow to red - Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch-5-6:9201.","prevState":"yellow","prevMsg":"Waiting for Elasticsearch"}
kibana-5-6            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-11-26T06:09:33Z","tags":["status","plugin:reporting@5.6.3","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from yellow to red - Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch-5-6:9201.","prevState":"yellow","prevMsg":"Waiting for Elasticsearch"}
kibana-5-6            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-11-26T06:09:33Z","tags":["status","plugin:elasticsearch@5.6.3","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from yellow to red - Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch-5-6:9201.","prevState":"yellow","prevMsg":"Waiting for Elasticsearch"}
kibana-5-6            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-11-26T06:09:33Z","tags":["status","plugin:searchprofiler@5.6.3","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to red - Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch-5-6:9201.","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
kibana-5-6            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-11-26T06:09:34Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch-5-6:9201/"}
kibana-5-6            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-11-26T06:09:34Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
kibana-5-6            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-11-26T06:09:34Z","tags":["status","plugin:ml@5.6.3","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to red - Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch-5-6:9201.","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
elasticsearch-5-6     | [2017-11-26T06:09:34,750][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [immunedata-cluster-5-6.node-1] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [eAlcHBJ2QVG58e0HJsgrdQ][immunedata-cluster-5-6.node-1][/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0] free: 1.9gb[7.4%], shards will be relocated away from this node
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:09:36,692][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch-5-6:9201/, :path=>"/"}
kibana-5-6            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-11-26T06:09:37Z","tags":["status","plugin:ml@5.6.3","info"],"pid":1,"state":"yellow","message":"Status changed from red to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch","prevState":"red","prevMsg":"Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch-5-6:9201."}
logstash-5-6          | [2017-11-26T06:09:37,366][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch-5-6:9201/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch-5-6:9201/][Manticore::SocketException] Connection refused (Connection refused)"}
kibana-5-6            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-11-26T06:09:37Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch-5-6:9201/"}
kibana-5-6            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-11-26T06:09:37Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
kibana-5-6            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-11-26T06:09:37Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch-5-6:9201/"}
kibana-5-6            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-11-26T06:09:37Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
kibana-5-6            | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-11-26T06:09:37Z","tags":
```

Answer (score 1):

You called elasticsearch service `elasticsearch-5-6` in your `docker-compose.yml`. That means that container with `elasticsearch` is available on address `http://elasticsearch-5-6:9200` for all other containers in your `docker-compose.yaml`. And it is available on address `http://127.0.0.1:9201` from the host machine.

In order to have workable ELK stack you need to change logstash config to:

```
http.host: "0.0.0.0"
path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.url: http://elasticsearch-5-6:9200
#xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: logstash_system
#xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: changeme
xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
```

and kibana config to:

```
server.name: kibana
server.host: "0"
elasticsearch.url: http://elasticsearch-5-6:9200
xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled: false
xpack.security.enabled: false
## Above I tired this - not working
#elasticsearch.username: elastic
#elasticsearch.password: changeme
#xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled: false
#xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled: true
# Extra:
ssl.verificationMode: false
```

Answer (score 0):

### EKL Cluster with Xpack disabled

You are missing with the `ELASTICSEARCH_URL: "http://elasticsearch:9200"` in kibana and `xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.url: http://elasticsearch:9200` in Logstash

here is the sample yml configuration ith all possible environment varibales defined in `environment`

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: '-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m'
      cluster.name: es-cluster
      node.name: es1
      network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
      discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
      discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: elasticsearch1
      xpack.security.enabled: 'false'
      xpack.monitoring.enabled: 'false'
      xpack.watcher.enabled: 'false'
      xpack.ml.enabled: 'false'
      http.cors.enabled : 'true'
      http.cors.allow-origin : "*"
      http.cors.allow-methods : OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
      http.cors.allow-headers : X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type, Content-Length
      logger.level: debug
    volumes:
      - /var/elasticsearch/db/elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    networks: 
      - elastic
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.6.0
    container_name: logstash
    ports:
      - 5044:5044
      - 5001:5001
    volumes:
      - /var/elasticsearch/logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xmx2048m -Xms2048m"
      http.host: 0.0.0.0
      xpack.monitoring.enabled: 'false'
      xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.url: http://elasticsearch:9200
    networks: 
      - elastic
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.6.0
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: "http://elasticsearch:9200"
      xpack.security.enabled: 'false'
      xpack.graph.enabled : 'false'
      xpack.ml.enabled : 'false'
      xpack.monitoring.enabled : 'false'
      xpack.watcher.enabled : 'false'
      xpack.reporting.enabled : 'false'
    ports: 
      - 5601:5601
    networks: 
      - elastic
    depends_on: 
      - elasticsearch

  elasticsearch-head:
    image: mobz/elasticsearch-head:5
    container_name: elasticsearch-head
    ports:
      - "9100:9100"
    networks: 
      - elastic
networks:
  elastic:
      driver: bridge
```